# Parallax Feature

Tags: html

I'm working on my personal website.

I can't figure out why the images for the parallax feature aren't appearing on anything except chrome browser.

For example, on my phone it doesn't work and on safari browser it doesn't work.

Everything is labeled correctly.

I have added bootstrap to the file.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sadly I have too little reputation to post this as a comment where it belongs, so I'll just post it as an answer.
Check out [Can i use..](http://caniuse.com/), a HTML5 support table. I suspect a combination of using em, as well as whatever css sits behind

```
class="body flex flex-horizontal-center flex-direction-col container"
```

to be the cause for your problem.

Comment: Mobile Safari usually uses an older version of WebKit (the rendering engine), while mobile chrome uses a rather new version and mobile chrome beta is often the latest and greatest. If it's not mission-critical to have support for mobile Safari, I'd just wait and see.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not working on Safari & on your phone because you're using the shorthand of the background. Some browsers don't fully support it. 
Maybe if you split the properties it may work.
Previous :

```
background: url("../images/IMG_UnicornCoders.jpeg") no-repeat fixed 50%;
```

After :

```
background: 50% url("../images/IMG_UnicornCoders.jpeg") no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
```